# How to disable "Received gossip status" log in akka?

Tags: akka, gossip

I use akka cluster in runtime i received log like this

```
    Received gossip status from [akka.tcp://test@ip:port], chunk [1] 
    of [1] containing [WeakUpdatesManagerCoordinatorState, 
    SeqUpdatesManagerCoordinatorState, EventBusMediatorCoordinatorState, 
    PresenceManagerCoordinatorState, shardakka-kv-MigrationsCoordinatorState, 
    GroupProcessorCoordinatorState, SessionCoordinatorState, WebrtcCallCoordinatorState, 
    SocialManagerCoordinatorState, GroupPresenceManagerCoordinatorState, 
    UserProcessorCoordinatorState]
```

How disable this log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this line in logback file

```
  <logger name="akka.cluster.ddata.Replicator" level="INFO"/>
```

I can't find any configuration to stop this log.